# Bipartite graph in Gephi

Tags: gephi

How do you construct  a csv for a bipartite graph. I have the following data set:

```
ID, Source, Target, Weight
1,00ash00,t3_ascto,-1
2,00ash00,t3_asll7,1
3,00ash00,t3_atawm,1
4,00ash00,t3_avosd,1
5,0-0,t3_6vlrz,1
6,0-0,t3_6vmwa,1
7,0-0,t3_6wdiv,1
8,0-0,t3_6wegp,1
9,0-0,t3_6wegz,1
10,00-,t3_ajdu3,-1
```

Source and Target columns represent the from-to aspect in a bipartite graph. I read somewhere that inorder to generate a graph, you need a node csv file(a mapping of the IDs with nodes) and an edges csv files. So how do i convert the above dataset and use it in these two files?

In case my approach is not right, suggest another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems to be an OK example of [CSV "spreadsheets" that gephi can import](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/spreadsheet/), except for one thing: it doesn't work with the space before each column name. So the column names should appear as follows in the file:

```
ID,Source,Target,Weight
```

Then by creating a new project or using an existing one, and by clicking the "Data Laboratory" button between "Overview" and "Preview", it should be no problem to [import the file into a gephi edges table](http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Import_CSV_Data).

Additional observations:

- It's a bipartite graph in that no source is a target and no target is a source.
- If you want to import it as an undirected graph, you can add a "Type" column that has the value "Undirected" for each edge (that is, row).
- Is the source identifier 00- perhaps intended to be 0-0? It's oddly similar.

Comment: I need to add the nodes.csv right, how do you think that should be?

Comment: Because, right now if i directly add the edges csv, it is going to throw an error saying `Edges table needs a source and a id column with a node id`

Comment: Yes, that is the error that you will fix by removing the spaces from before the column names, particularly "Source".